# ip controller wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-login, redirection-wordpress-plugin

I want a wordpress plugin which it's record ip of new users and when they try to log in with diffrent ip it's block they signin request and show any message like : please try to log in with ur original ip

I don't want a new plugin .I want a plugin is allready in wordpress plugins ,I researched And try some plugins of ip logging but no one of working

I have created a plugin but it have some errors if there any php expert can help also

I have tried some plugins like :
IP based login
IP logging
WP security

Comment: "I want a plugin is allready in wordpress plugins" - Asking for recommendations for plugins/libraries is generally discouraged on this site.

Comment: "I have created a plugin but it have some errors if there any php expert can help also" - If you post that code, we might be able to help you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

these plugins might help you.
AIOWPS works well, i am using it like two years

1. All In One WP Security & Firewall
2. Wordfence Security
3. iThemes Security